# VBA - how to conditionally skip a for loop iteration

Tags: vba, conditional-statements, loops

I have a for loop over an array. What I want to do is test for a certain condition in the loop and skip to the next iteration if true:

```
For i = LBound(Schedule, 1) To UBound(Schedule, 1)
    If (Schedule(i, 1) < ReferenceDate) Then
        PrevCouponIndex = i
        Continue   '*** THIS LINE DOESN'T COMPILE, nor does "Next"
    End If
    DF = Application.Run("SomeFunction"....)
    PV = PV + (DF * Coupon / CouponFrequency)
Next
```

I Know I can do:

```
 If (Schedule(i, 1) < ReferenceDate) Then Continue For
```

but I want to be able to record the last value of i in the PrevCouponIndex variable.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You said: "I Know I can do: `If (Schedule(i, 1) < ReferenceDate) Then Continue For`"  Are you sure about that?  `Continue` is not a VBA keyword.

Comment: @mwolfe02 - no not sure, but saw in examples somewhere (cpearson?)

Comment: may have been a VB.NET example

Comment: Continue is a VB keyword (in VS2017) but not for this, unfortunately.  Probably saw an example in C# (or C++ or C).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Couldn't you just do something simple like this?

```
For i = LBound(Schedule, 1) To UBound(Schedule, 1)
  If (Schedule(i, 1) < ReferenceDate) Then
     PrevCouponIndex = i
  Else
     DF = Application.Run("SomeFunction"....)
     PV = PV + (DF * Coupon / CouponFrequency)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Indeed, is exactly what I have done :) But still it bugs me I have to wrap stuff in the Else piece. Thanks

Comment: +1 @RichardH well you have to use an `IF` for the test so this isn't that expensive codewise. You should though ensure that the most common outcome is that `Schedule(i, 1)` is less than `ReferenceDate` to avoid executing the `Else`more often than necessary. Otherwise use `(ReferenceDate>=Schedule(i, 1))`. (if the test is 50/50 then no need for optimisation)

Comment: Just might get a bit messy with numerous nested ifs... if for example you need to check quite a few Application.Match results within each iteration for not finding a matching before using the results.  But so be it, there are worse things in life!

Answer (score 217):

VBA does not have a `Continue` or any other equivalent keyword to immediately jump to the next loop iteration.  I would suggest a judicious use of `Goto` as a workaround, especially if this is just a contrived example and your real code is more complicated:

```
For i = LBound(Schedule, 1) To UBound(Schedule, 1)
    If (Schedule(i, 1) < ReferenceDate) Then
        PrevCouponIndex = i
        Goto NextIteration
    End If
    DF = Application.Run("SomeFunction"....)
    PV = PV + (DF * Coupon / CouponFrequency)
    '....'
    'a whole bunch of other code you are not showing us'
    '....'
    NextIteration:
Next
```

If that is really all of your code, though, @Brian is absolutely correct.  Just put an `Else` clause in your `If` statement and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip re the GoTo (VBA - beaming you back to 1964)

Comment: GoTo is EVIL! Do not use GoTo or your code goes to hell! Seriously though, please do not use GoTo in your code.

Comment: @George: GoTo can be abused (which is why I qualified my statement; see [judicious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/judicious)), but it is not inherently evil.  Seriously though, it is **impossible** to write robust VBA without the Goto statement simply because you need it for error handling (i.e., `On Error Goto`).

Comment: @mwolfe02: On Error Goto is OK (a limitation of the language that's too old to fix it by brining it inline with try/catch), but anywhere else Goto should be avoided at all costs. Use other control flow mechanisms. This is recommended by most programmers and Microsoft too. In the past 15-20 years of my VB6/VBA experience, I've never used Goto once other than in On Error case. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c.aspx

Comment: @George: What I'm recommending here is a workaround for another limitation of the language (no `Continue` statement).  One can argue that the use of `Continue` in other languages should be avoided and therefore should be avoided here as well.  In some ways, the link you posted makes my point.  The link is to the `GoTo` statement in VB.Net.  VB.Net has both structured error handling and `Continue For`/`Continue Do` statements.  There is truly no need for `GoTo` in VB.Net; I suspect it was left in place largely to support easier conversion of existing VBA/VB6 code.

Comment: @mwolfe02: There is no need for Goto in VB6 either. Brian had a perfect replacement for Goto with an Ifcontrol flow mechanism. Goto would over-complicate and confuse things. If you disagree, please post a piece of code where Goto works better than alternative control flow mechanism.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I do not believe that tradeoff is beneficial. I'd rather have nesting (which isn't a big deal in most cases) than have a messy and unpredictable control flow. Nesting is not gonna break your code, GoTo may. What I am saying is, you might have an OK solution in a very small and isolated scenario. The risk, however, is great if you decide to expand the code in the future. Its just not worth it.

Comment: @George I've seen nesting that doesn't break *code*, but wrecks one's *brain* ;)

Comment: @Mat's Mug I can definitely agree to that!

Comment: `GoTo` seems to be the most logical way to overcome VBA’s lack of the `continue` statement.  So I typed it!  It works well!  Just this once won’t hurt…Everyone else is doing it; so it can’t be that bad…I can quit using `GoTo` anytime I like…

Answer (score 43):

You can use a kind of `continue` by using a nested `Do ... Loop While False`:

```
'This sample will output 1 and 3 only

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3: Do

    If i = 2 Then Exit Do 'Exit Do is the Continue

    Debug.Print i

Loop While False: Next i
```

Comment: interesting ..better than using goto!

Comment: This is awesome

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: Very elegant and nice

Comment: Clever! I would hate to be the guy that comes across that with no comments though. lol

Comment: By far the better answer.  Especially with comments.

Comment: I agree that this solution has a certain cleverness, but disagree that it's elegant.  It actually obscures the point of what's being accomplished, makes the coding much less self-evident, requiring commentary to explain it (as noted by Caltor).

Comment: This is very clever (though I don't necessarily mean that as a compliment...[Don't Write Clever Code](https://nolongerset.com/dont-write-clever-code/)).  This is the sort of nonsense you get when you treat good _general advice_ ("Don't use GoTo in your code") as an _inviolable rule_ never to be broken.

Answer (score 15):

`Continue For` isn't valid in VBA or VB6.

From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zekeaa%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it looks to have been introduced into VB.Net in VS 2005./Net 2.

As the others have said there's not really an option other than to use `Goto` or an `Else`.

Answer (score 5):

Hi I am also facing this issue  and I solve this using below example code

```
For j = 1 To MyTemplte.Sheets.Count

       If MyTemplte.Sheets(j).Visible = 0 Then
           GoTo DoNothing        
       End If 


'process for this for loop
DoNothing:

Next j
```

Comment: Not sure why this had been down-voted and the next answer has over 100 up votes, and they are the same answer!

Comment: Probably because this answer was written 5 years after that answer, and is the exact same concept. Why should this receive upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

VB6 , VBA doesnt have continue. Following HACK is what I have been using since VB3 days ie year 1992. I have been using "for dummy = 1 to 1 : exit for : next dummy" loop. The "exit for" inside dummy inner loop  implements continue for actual outer loop

```
Sub Print_all_integers_except_multiples_of_3()
  Dim i As Integer, dummy As Integer
  For i = 1 To 100
  For dummy = 1 To 1 ' dummy only to implement Continue For i
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then Exit For ' implements Continue For i
    Debug.Print i
  Next dummy
  Next i
End Sub
```

So inner dummy loop has only one iteration. And Exit For statement inside the inner dummy loop will implement "Continue For". Also, I dont indent For Dummy loop. So it becomes easily visible that this dummy loop is "dummy". And sometimes, I use variable name "Continue1" instead of Dummy to make it more obvious.

- Rahul Chimanbhai Mehta , MehtaRahulC@yahoo.com , +91-98251-27780

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try putting it all in the end if and use a else to skip the code this will make it so that you are able not use the GoTo.

```
                        If 6 - ((Int_height(Int_Column - 1) - 1) + Int_direction(e, 1)) = 7 Or (Int_Column - 1) + Int_direction(e, 0) = -1 Or (Int_Column - 1) + Int_direction(e, 0) = 7 Then
                Else
                    If Grid((Int_Column - 1) + Int_direction(e, 0), 6 - ((Int_height(Int_Column - 1) - 1) + Int_direction(e, 1))) = "_" Then
                        Console.ReadLine()
                    End If
                End If
```