# Three And (&)'s into an if statement VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm trying to delete all worksheets, but three, in a workbook using "and's" into "if... then" statements however is deleting one of them. What I wrote is the following:

```
Sub delete()

For Each Sheet In Application.Worksheets

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If (Sheet.Name <> "Close Price" And Sheet.Name <> "Parameters" And Sheet.Name <> "Stock") Then

  Sheet.delete

End If

Next Sheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I also tried the following:

```
Sub delete()

For Each Sheet In Application.Worksheets

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

If (Sheet.Name <> "Close Price" And Sheet.Name <> "Parameters") Then
  If (Sheet.Name <> "Stock") Then

  Sheet.delete

  End If
End If

Next Sheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

but is not working either. It respects the "Close Price" and "Parameters" worksheets but not the "Stock" worksheet.

Do you know how can I solve it?.

Thanks a lot and all the best.
grd_aa

Comment: Perhaps your Stock sheet name has a leading or trailing space

Comment: I just tested the first code block and it works as intended. I believe @chrisneilsen has your answer.

Comment: Also check for case sensitivity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheets can be deleted **at once** using array of sheet names. In the `For-Each` loop collect the names of sheets you wish to delete into an array. Then just call `Worksheets(sheetsToDeteleArrayHere).delete` so all the sheets in the array will be deleted at once. HTH

*Note: with Trim(sheet-name) it is ensured that the leading and/or ending spaces are not part of the  comparison.)*

```
Sub delete()
    Dim sheet
    Dim sheetsToDetele

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each sheet In Application.Worksheets

        If Trim(sheet.name) = "Close Price" Then GoTo continue
        If Trim(sheet.name) = "Parameters" Then GoTo continue
        If Trim(sheet.name) = "Stock" Then GoTo continue

        If IsArray(sheetsToDetele) Then
            ReDim Preserve sheetsToDetele(1 To UBound(sheetsToDetele) + 1)
        Else
            ReDim sheetsToDetele(1 To 1)
        End If

        sheetsToDetele(UBound(sheetsToDetele)) = sheet.name

continue:
    Next sheet

    If Not IsArray(sheetsToDetele) Then _
        Exit Sub

    Application.Worksheets(sheetsToDetele).delete

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Isn't there an "avoid using GoTo" rule in VBA?

Comment: @Chrismas007 There is no such avoid using GoTo _rule_. Such _rules_ are generally guidelines. [VBA provides no method for immediately going to the next item in a for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8680815/1316573). This is the typical workaround... not to say it's necessary to have coded it this way. You only need avoid GoTo if it makes your code hard to read, this is not a good example of a bad GoTo

Comment: /sarcasm fails on you sir.

Comment: Also a simple `If x Or y Or z Then... Else` would avoid the need for GoTo.

Comment: With GoTo continue i have tryied to reduce nesting, so code looks more clear to me. But it is possible to use Ifs, or even Select-Cases, it is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

as you say that the if statement is not respecting the third `and`, I would change it to a `Select Case`, as only delete when the name doesn't match any of the others that are listed in the case statements
(I know I can put all the names onto one line

```
    Case "Close Price", "Parameters", "Stock"
```

I just think it looks tidier this way:)

```
Sub delete()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each Sheet In Application.Worksheets
    Select Case Sheet.Name
        Case "Close Price"
        Case "Parameters"
        Case "Stock"
        Case Else
            Sheet.delete
    End Select
Next Sheet

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "I just think it looks tidier this way:)" We could always use good reviewers on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba?sort=newest&pageSize=50)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you delete `sheet`, you are altering the enumeration to the point where the loop cannot continue as the integrity has been compromised.

Instead, when you need to do this, use a loop based on the index and then work *backwards*. This way when you delete a sheet, the next iterations are not impacted.

```
Sub delete()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim i As Integer
    ' Work backwards so if/when a sheet is deleted,
    '  the indexes are not changed
    For i = Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1

        If Sheets(i).Name <> "Close Price" _
            And Sheets(i).Name <> "Parameters" _
            And Sheets(i).Name <> "Stock" _
            Then

            Sheets(i).Delete
        End If

    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Jason, the problem is the name of his sheet. I just tested the first block of code OP posted and it works just as intended. There's no need to loop backwards here. OP is doing a `ForEach` not a `For` loop.

Comment: @RubberDuck - I just tried using the loop construct he is using and I got erratic results. I didn't use his names, rather Sheet1, Sheet2, etc. but changing to the loop to use by index it worked.

Comment: Did you enough worksheets so that there was always at least one left? Because I've tested it too, and OPs code *works*. It doesn't rely on an index at all. Hence, no reason to loop backward.

Comment: @RubberDuck - Tested with 4 (so Sheet4 was left). It left Sheet1 and then Sheet3 the second go around. This is very odd. I'm using Excel 2013 - what version are you using?

Comment: @RubberDuck, as per my expierence, using iteration through the collection causes several problems. I agree with Jason Faulkner

Comment: Thanks for your answers are really appreciated. I tried with the provided code and is still deleting the "Stock" worksheet. I also checked the names and the problem is not there either. Actually, the first instruction when I start the main routine is to delete everything but "Parameters" and "Stock" ans it's working fine. However, at the end, it seems to me, that the if doesn't respect the third "and". I really don't understand why.

Comment: My target is no matter what happened during the routine the worksheet "Stock" remains in the file (obviously, "Parameters" also). Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?. Regards, grd_aa

Comment: @grd_aa - So if you move "Stock" to the first `IF` condition and "Close Price" to the last, is "Close Price" ignored?