# VBA stop execution of current iteration of loop

Tags: vba

How to stop execution of current iteration of for loop statement ?
`Exit` ends execution of whole loop, have I realy use `goto` ?

Comment: This is a poorly written question.  Mainly because you haven't explained if you want to skip ONE iteration of the loop or Exit the loop completely.  Under what conditions would you like to skip/exit?  What have you tried so far other than `Exit`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA - how to conditionally skip a for loop iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680640/vba-how-to-conditionally-skip-a-for-loop-iteration)

Answer (score 3):

You'll usually want to skip an iteration when a given condition is met - you have 2 options in VBA:

1. Wrap the loop body in an `If` block:

   ```
       For i = 1 to 100
           If SomeCondition Then
               ' interesting iterations
           End If
       Next
   ```
2. Use `GoTo` to skip an iteration (and reduce nesting):

   ```
       For i = 1 to 100
           If Not SomeCondition Then GoTo Skip

           ' interesting iterations

   Skip:
       Next
   ```

Yes, `GoTo` is bad. But this is an old language, and `GoTo` *does* have legitimate uses - that's one of them. If you keep your code clean and [extract the loop body into its own procedure](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/wiki/Features#refactorings), there shouldn't be any readability issues with using it.