# Continue For doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the Continue For statement in Excel and it throws a compilation error: "Expected expression". This is the code:

```
For i = 3 To num
If Cells(i, 19) = "" Then
continue for
End If
Next i
```

Why does this happen?
PS: this a simplified version of the actual code.

Comment: continue for does not exist in vba, because in most cases there is a way to rearrange the statement in the loop to make it unneeded.  If you show the actual code we may be able to help re work the logic.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` and you'll see that `Continue` isn't a keyword in VBA, you can use a `GoTo` instead.

Comment: I want it to go to the next loop iteration. That is, I need it to add +1 to i and start over.

Comment: @ScottCraner I edited my question to make myself clear.

Comment: If the condition is met then do nothing and the loop will move to the next loop without doing anything.  It is a matter of using the correct if statements.  In this instance you would do an if statement of `If Cells(i, 19) <> "" Then` and do those things.  that way if it is blank it will do nothing and the next loop will fire.

Comment: For the record I have rolled back the question to the state prior to the last edit, so that it is clear what the original question was - the question should not be edited to reflect incorporation of the chosen answer, as that makes it difficult for later users to actually see what the initial problem was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - how to conditionally skip a for loop iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680640/vba-how-to-conditionally-skip-a-for-loop-iteration)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest would be to simply process when the condition is not met.

```
For i = 3 To num
    If Cells(i, 19) <> "" Then
        'execute the rest of the processing
    End If
Next i
```

Avoid incrementing the `i` in a For Next loop. A `GoTo` is discouraged and largely unnecessary (as demonstrated above).

Alternates would be For Each in a [Range.SpecialCells method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) of [xlCellTypeConstants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836534.aspx) if the values are typed values and not returned from a formula.

Comment: Are there any major practical differences in using `Cells() <> ""` over `IsEmpty(Cells())`?

Comment: `Cells(...) <> ""` is kind of a catch-all that matches truly blank cells as well as cells containing zero-length string results from formulas. `Not IsEmpty(Cells(...))` catches only truly blank cells. I also use `If CBool(Len(Cells(...))) Then` .

Comment: Thanks! I had it backwards - I thought `<> ""` would catch almost everything, but `IsEmpty()` would catch every type of empty cell.  I like your last one, but why use `Cbool`? Wouldn't `If Len(Cells())` on an empty cell return 0, making it `FALSE`? does CBool force that into a boolean, whereas if you didn't use it, it'd return the string `0`, and thus not `FALSE` as VBA reads it? (...did that question make sense?)

Comment: `CBool` is a definitive conversion from a number to a boolean. While it can be said that False is zero and anything that is not False is True, in reality, VBA doesn't always treat a non-zero number as True without CBool. Best to be definitive and it's a low-impact visual reminder that you are evaluating a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as the OP. It looks like VBA does not have a "continue for" command.  The **.Net** For statement does, so it is easy to land on documentation like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement) and think that VBA has it as well.

My solution was to use a goto statement.  I know, I know ... Gotos are disfavored.  But if used carefully they can really clean up your code.

```
    For intRow = 1 To intLastRow
        strAddr = "a" & intRow
        If wsDest.Range(strAddr) = "X" Then
            GoTo next_intRow
        End If
        
        ... statements
        
next_intRow:
    Next intRow
```

And I respectfully disagree with the first answer. While I rarely use continue statements, they are occasionally very helpful.  Without them you have to use the NOT of your elimination logic and wrap potentially large blocks of code in if-endif statements, which I think makes the code much messier and harder to read.