# Continue to next loop if file is not present in the current loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am opening a file in each loop and if file is not present I have to skip that loop and move to next but somehow my code is not working.

```vb
For i = 1 To lngLstRowTemp    

  On Error Resume Next

  Set WrkBk_StateSummary = Application.Workbooks.Open(File_StateSummary)

  On Error GoTo 0

  If Not WrkBk_StateSummary Is Nothing Then

    Set WrkBk_StateSummary = Application.Workbooks.Open(File_StateSummary)       
         
    'Here I am opening the file WrkBk_StateSummary,
    'but if file is not present I want to goto next loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample isn't complete, but I expect you want this:

```vb
For i = 1 To lngLstRowTemp
    If Len(Dir(File_StateSummary)) > 0 Then
        Set WrkBk_StateSummary = Application.Workbooks.Open(File_StateSummary)
    End If
Next i
```

It first checks the existence of the file in the variable `File_StateSummary` and if it exists, it opens it.

If this isn't what you need, please provide more information, or more complete code.

Tip:
If you want to avoid 'arrow code' (too much `If`s), then you can use this neat syntax: [VBA - how to conditionally skip a for loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680640/vba-how-to-conditionally-skip-a-for-loop-iteration/48984124#48984124)

Comment: Yes , so if the file is not present it should skip this loop(Dont perform the next steps of the current loop ) and continue to next loop

Comment: So the question is answered?

Comment: @karanarora: You're welcome. Please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find that it solved your problem.